# exec_start, exec_die events happening frequently

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, swarm

I have a bunch of containers that are running using swarm. when i monitor the `docker events` i see lots of `exec_create` -> `exec_start` -> `exec_die` events whenever a HEALTHCHECK is run.

However, the containers aren't restarted. The uptime is in days. I'm bit confused about how to interpret these events.

Hope someone can point me to a good documentation on these events.

Answer (score 2):

The `exec_create` appears when someone runs command `docker exec...`